# How to style a list ul to be a square

Tags: css, html, coding-style

I have this ul

```
 <ul>
<li>image</li>
<li>image</li>
<li>image</li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know how to css this ul to an suare like that?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MQJi.jpg

Comment: do you have some css to show what have you tried? also there is some libraries in javascript to get this, like masonry jquery

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```css
ul{
    width:300px;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li:nth-child(1){
    height:210px;
}
ul li{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    background:orange;
    height:100px;
    margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>image</li>
<li>image</li>
<li>image</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
ul{
  width: 480px;
  height: 400px
}
ul li{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  list-style: none
}
ul li{
  height: 50%;
}
ul li:first-child{
  height: 100%;
  background: green
}
ul li:nth-child(2){
  background: red
}
ul li:last-child{
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>image</li>
  <li>image</li>
  <li>image</li>
</ul>
```